# Trouble with ASP.NET data source parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, c#-4.0

I have a `GridView` and I want to add some more parameters to the DataSource. One of the parameters is called `symbols` and is a `DataTable`, and I'm not sure how to add it. Here's my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView  
    ID="grdTrades" 
    runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="tradeId"
    DataSource="srcTrades"
    EnablePersistedSelection="true"            
    AllowPaging="true" 
    AllowSorting="true"
    PageSize = "10" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"         
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="tradeId" HeaderText="TradeId"  SortExpression="tradeId" />
        ... some more columns ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my current data source.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource
    id="srcTrades" 
    TypeName="DatabaseComponent.DBUtil" 
    SelectMethod="GetTrades" 
    DeleteMethod="DeleteTrade"             
    runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="tradeTypeId" ControlID="ddlTradeTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="dateFrom" ControlID="txtDateFrom" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="dateTo" ControlID="txtDateTo" PropertyName="Text" />            
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="tradeId" ControlId="grdTrades" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  />
    </DeleteParameters> 
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I want to pass an extra parameter called `symbols` which is a `DataTable`. I populate the `DataTable` with this code:

`DataTable symbols = GetSelectedItems("symbol", listSymbols);`

`GetSelectedItems` looks like this:

```
private DataTable GetSelectedItems(string column, ListBox _listbox)
{
    DataTable items = new DataTable();
    items.Columns.Add(column, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

    foreach (ListItem item in _listbox.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            DataRow dr = items.NewRow();
            dr[column] = item.Value;
            items.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

I did try and bind the data myself and removing the `ObjectDataSource` entirely but then the sorting and paging events weren't handled. How would you solve this little issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xml type (and a simple string SelectParameter) instead of DataTable:

1. Page_Load: Serialize selected items
   of listbox into xml
   and assign
   his text into the SelectParameter
2. GetTrades: Deserialize xml from the SelectParameter into a List<> local variable

Comment: Thanks - could you provide an example of populating the SelectParameter with the XML in Page_Load?

Answer (score 1):

```
    XElement x = new XElement("root",
        from i in _listbox.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
        where i.Selected
        select new XElement("row", i.Value));
    string s = x.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks but how to assign that as a SelectParameter?